# How to test vue component method with ajax request in Mocha?

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js

I have a vue component with methods send out ajax request, I tried `done()` provided by Mocha to test this method, but it seems do not work correctly by the coverage report(the success and complete methods are not covered according to the report). The codes are as follows:

- Vue component code in demo.vue

```

```
loadData: function(cb) {
      var that = this;
      $.ajax(
        {
          url: "/api/nodesWithTask",
          async: true,
          success: function(data) {
            that.nodes = data;
          },
          complete: function(xhr, status) {
            if (cb && typeof (cb) == 'function') {
              cb.call();
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }
```

```

- Test code

```

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import demo from '@/components/demo'
describe('demo.vue', () => {
  var mockData = {"id":"abc"};
  var server;
  var vm;
  before(function () { 
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); 
    //mock response for ajax request
    server.respondWith("/api/nodesWithTask",[200,{"Content-Type":"application/json"},JSON.stringify(mockData)]);
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(demo);
    vm = new Constructor().$mount();
  });

  after(function () { server.restore(); });

  it('load data async', (done) => {
    vm.loadData(function(){
      done();
    });
  })
})
```

```

Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Advised by my leader, I find one `magic` config option of sinon fake server as follows

```
before(function () { 
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create(); 
    //mock response for ajax request
    server.respondWith("/api/nodesWithTask",[200,{"Content-Type":"application/json"},JSON.stringify(mockData)]);
    server.respondImmediately = true;
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(demo);
    vm = new Constructor().$mount();
  });
```

After I set the respondImmediately option to true, the test can run correctly.